# Is it possible to use multiple windows in vscode in remote (ssh) development?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in remote projects most of the time, using ssh remote explorer in vscode. When working on local projects, I usually use multiple windows as I'm not comfortable with the split screen function due to small screen size.

However, opening up an additional window while working doesn't seem possible for remote projects, as I'm unable to drag a file into a newly opened window. Also, "connect in new window" doesn't seem to work while one connection to the same project is active.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: vscode 1.85 supports "Floating editor windows", and should suit your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@obfish's comment solves it: Floating editor windows are now supported since 1.85, also for remote connections

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same issue as you. I work on a remote with SSH connnection.
As a work around I open second window in another folder(opening the same folder does not work) and then I drag and drop the files I want to view in the second one.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35365622)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible
got to the search window: >Workspaces:Duplicate as Workspace in new Window

than you can open it, even drag files between the windows.